# sum of iid random variables with partial tail bound

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose I have a random variable $X$ with mean zero satisfying, for all $t<1$,
$$
P[ |X| > t ] < 2\exp(-c t^2).
$$

Is it true that for some universal constant $C$,
for all $t<1$,
$$
P[ |X_1+\cdots+X_n|/n > t ] < 2\exp(-c C n t^2)
$$
where $X_i$ are iid samples of $X$.

Without the condition on $t$ this follows from equivalent characterizations of subgaussian RVs.

From an external assumption from my application, I know $X$ is bounded (and therefore) subgaussian, but I want a bound in terms of $c$.

Comment: It would help if you clarify what "for $t<1$" means: For all $t<1$? For a specific $t<1$?  Either way, the variable $X$ you give is not necessarily bounded or subGaussian.   In fact it can have infinite variance. For example suppose $|X|\geq 2$ always.

Comment: Thanks, clarified. That $X$ is bounded is from an external assumption.

Comment: I assume $c>0$. The condition $P[|X|>t] < 2 e^{-ct^2}$ for all $t<1$  is useless if $2 e^{-c} > 1$.

Comment: There is also no apparent connection between $X$ and $X_i$, and nothing is mentioned about independence assumptions on $\{X_i\}$.